# Django Rest - CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Got a weird scenario. I am on the Django Rest browser api with a logged in user.
When I update it is okay. But when I try to create a user, this error shows:

CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.

it also auto logged out me every single time.

In views.py, I already have added

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Still same error and scenario. 
In my settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
}
```

Anyone experienced this?

Comment: What's the Django auth backend ? What about middlewares ?

Comment: @Linovia, `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` included

Comment: You can make your view of rest as csrf_exempt.

Comment: csrf_exempt won't work with DRF views.

Comment: @bazinga what about (Django) sessions ? Are they configured ? what's their backends ?

Comment: @Linovia
 for installed_apps:
`'django.contrib.sessions', `

for middleware:
`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',`
`'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',`

Comment: Since I'm doing REST API, I've deleted the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'. You can do the same maybe

Comment: When I removed `SessionAuthentication` in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` the csrf error is gone, although when creating data/POST, it is 404